# Getting mysql error while fetching record

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the following error while joining the SQL query to fetch the record.

```
 #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'v'
```

I am explaining my query below.

```
$sql="select v.owner_id,v.driver_id,v.reg_no,v.brand,v.model,v.vehicle_type,m.category_id,m.id,m.model_name,m.manufacture_id,m.image,mn.id,mn.manufacture_name,c.cat_id,c.category_name from cb_vehicle_info as v inner join cb_vechile_model as m on v.model=m.id inner join cb_vechile_manufacture as mn on m.manufacture_id=mn.id inner join cb_vechile_category v.vehicle_type=c.cat_id where v.driver_id=:driver_id and v.vehicle_type=:vehicle_type";
```

Here I am joining the multiple tables to fetch the record from the table but it's throwing the above error.

Comment: You never aliased cb_vechile_category

Comment: If you had made your query readable to yourself you would have spotted the problem straight away.

Comment: @Drakula Predator The fact that the query was in one long line was the basic problem of the question. You should not have formatted it.

Comment: No offence taken, and I didn't expect any other reaction, but please think about it again. An edit should not change the essence of a question.

Comment: i agree here with @KIKOSoftware SQL "onelines" are **terrible** for reading and maintenance and not to mention **error prone** ..  The topicstarter should avoid writing those long SQL onliners and use formatting in the PHP also for SQL queries.

Comment: Also iam tempend to vlose close this question as a simple typographical error.as i think it should be `cb_vechile_category as c` or `cb_vechile_category c` to make it work as it seams the c alias is never defined but it is used.

Comment: Yes, it is basically a simply syntax error. But even these simple errors can be difficult to solve, and there are already two answers. So, closing it is not needed, I think.

Comment: I voted to close the question. Removed my answer also as I feel it's not good to answer typographical mistake answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you ommited `as c on` for the category in your query:

```
select
    v.owner_id,v.driver_id,v.reg_no,v.brand,v.model,v.vehicle_type,m.category_id,m.id,m.model_name,m.manufacture_id,m.image,mn.id,mn.manufacture_name,c.cat_id,c.category_name 
from 
    cb_vehicle_info as v 
inner 
    join cb_vechile_model as m on v.model=m.id 
inner 
    join cb_vechile_manufacture as mn on m.manufacture_id=mn.id 
inner join 
    cb_vechile_category as c on v.vehicle_type=c.cat_id 
where 
    v.driver_id=:driver_id 
and 
    v.vehicle_type=:vehicle_type
```